# ASP.net and Word 365 API

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, office365

So i am starting to learn the Office 365 API's, i have some experience with C# and ASP.net. But now i was wondering is there a way to make website which allows me to edit documents with Word Online and then download them to my server for example.

I know that i can download user files using the [Office File API's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/files-rest-operations), but is there a way to integrate the Word Online editor? The base idea is to create a very simple website which will allow me to create/edit files form the backend (admin interface) using the word online editor and then have these files available for download on the frontend.

The question is not about creating something practical so i don't want to use a alternative editor like ckeditor, mostly i want to see if it's possible and if so how can i do it.

Comment: From backend, do you mean code? Or an admin interface?

Comment: @mason admin interface

Comment: Office365 Already allows editing Word online via Office Web Apps. So Office365/WebApp can be your Admin back-end and you can use Office365 APIs in your Front-end to download the files